# Calculate gravity between two intersecting bodies

Tags: 2d, game-design, simulations

I've been working on a 2D gravity simulator for some time and I'd like to add some surrealism to it by creating planets that can't collide with other planets (passing right through them).

The problem is, as distance between two bodies approaches zero, gravity goes to infinity - causing planets to slingshot when they're intersecting. Stopping gravity from being applied for a pair of bodies as soon as they touch looks odd as their velocity will suddenly go from accelerating to constant until they get to the other side.

Is there a function that gives me the best of both worlds or should I just leave the planets not being affected by gravity while intersecting other bodies?

Comment: Are the bodies always circular? Are their radii consistent or potentially distinct?

Comment: @DMGregory yes bodies are always circular. Their radii vary wildly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing what you're currently doing and disable the "real" gravity simulation once the two bodies overlap in 2D. **But** rather than set the velocity to a constant, keep applying whatever the most-recently computed acceleration of each body was. I'd guess that cheating the formula in this way would be less noticeable to a player?

Comment: This would also be my answer. However, to avoid constantly keeping the last acceleration applied to every body stored around somewhere, it can be calculated by taking the equation for the acceleration of each when they are the combined radii away from each other and integrating it with respect to time. The cap can be only on the acceleration caused by both gravitating towards one another, so the acceleration caused by other non-colliding bodies is not capped.

Comment: That sounds significantly smarter than my "math iz hard" solution, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make your simulation "2 and a half" dimensional by giving each body a Z depth.  Z is ignored for draw location (only X and Y apply there), but is used for calculating distance between objects for gravity.

Having depth adds an actual separation between overlapping bodies, thus avoiding the zero distance / infinite gravity situation. Different Z values will give you different amounts of interaction.  It also lets you detect actual collisions of items if they share the same Z depth.

This Z depth also allows you to choose rendering order, and even apply scaling based on Z distance.

Comment: This answer is clever but I think it would be of difficult implementation given that I want amount of interaction to be consistent with their mass as if all bodies shared the same Z plane, even if the body is _"uncollidable"_.

To get to that result having bodies on different planes I'd have to apply stronger forces on longer Z distances, which would probably cause the infinity issue to appear again as a side-effect.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Almost two years later, I noticed there's a better and more realistic way of calculating the gravity being applied for two intersecting bodies.

Note that this is more unstable than previous answers, and will usually require a high iteration count to maintain energy conservation.

If one picks a point inside a hollow planet, [it's known that no gravity will be applied to this point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/182688/what-would-happen-if-i-were-to-fall-into-a-massive-hollow-planet). With that in mind we can safely assume that, for any given point `p1` of planet A that is intersecting with planet B, any given point of planet B `p2` that is further away from its center than `p1` is, isn't going to exert any gravity on `p1`.

[image]
<sup>`Point A` refers to any point in the pink planet's surface that is in the intersection with the blue planet</sup>

What this means for our calculation is that we can first calculate the point of collision between the two masses, then calculate the gravity as if their radii were only big enough so to touch the point of collision (so their radii is the distance between the planet's center and the point of collision). This will make it so the mass never high enough to push gravity to infinity, no matter the distance between the centers.

[image]
<sup>*"Corrected masses"* are only used when solving for gravity</sup>